# how to add array names to form inputs in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, laravel-5

I am new in `Laravel 5.4` environment. I used `Codeigniter` before and  now I switched to `Laravel`.

**Question 1:**

In `Codeigniter` we could initialize array as input name to manage them easily like this :

```
<input type="text" name="vehicle[vehicle_no][]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" />
<input type="text" name="vehicle[make][]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" />
<input type="text" name="vehicle[model][]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" />
<input type="text" name="vehicle[chassis_no][]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" />
<input type="text" name="vehicle[engine][]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" />
<input type="text" name="vehicle[color][]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" />
<input type="text" name="vehicle[type][]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" />
```

Now I want to implement this in `Laravel 5.4`. How can I do that?

**Question 2:**

Using `Laravel Form library` is necessary or we can simply use `HTML`?

For example, using:

```
<input type="text" name="vehicle[chassis_no][]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" />
```

instead of

```
{!! Form::input('vehicle')!!}
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did in CodeIgnitor is nothing special or specific to that framework. That's just standard html. You can do the same in Laravel blade view files.

In laravel, once the form is submitted with the above html form fields, you can access the data like this for example:

```
foreach ($request->vehicle['chassis_no'] as $index => $vechicleChasisNo) {
    // ...
}
```

As for `Form` library - it comes down to preference - you can use it if you want or or not.